# "The specified printer has been deleted" message

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer, network-printer

Attempting to print or even view printer preferences has been throwing this error all afternoon and there's been no sign of any relevant troubleshooting solutions on a google search.

Any ideas what could be causing this and how it can be solved?

Comment: solution: The standard Windows style; Delete nonfunctional printer in the Control panel > Printers, reboot (to ensure nothing is left dangling), then reinstall the driver for your printer (which might require yet another reboot to get complete).

Comment: already tried removing it and re-adding from the network, it printed a successful test page but threw the same error when trying to print a pdf

Comment: use this command **printui.exe /s /t2** and remove the printer drivers, re-add the printers after this

Comment: I suggest that you remove ALL printers, reboot, then reinstall. Unless your PDF viewer has got something wrong and needs a "beating" in the same style.